# i'm facing error in pages\_document.js in nextjs

Tags: next.js, render, document, server-error

i'm facing this error  in pages_document.js >>>>

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

pages_document.js (5:31) @ Function.getInitialProps

```
 class MyDocument extends Document {
      static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
      }
```

my code is >>>

```
    import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1" /> */}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: Although the error may refer to `_document.js`, the error is most likely somewhere else. Make sure you're importing/exporting all your React components correctly across your app.